# How do I automate a login of a client using Java?

Tags: java, keypress

So I've been trying to automatically login through a WinSCP client. I have all the of credentials saved in the client for when I open it. If I manually press `Enter` on my keyboard, the client will log in. I tried using the `robot` method credited to @Slanec

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

However, when I checked Java API this just seems to check whether or not a key is pressed by a user?

Anyways... this is the code I currently have. The code opens the command prompt and enters a specified file path to open up a specific application WinSCP. Once the application is open I want the `Enter` Key to be pressed so that I can log in. If I manually press the enter key during this process it will work fine. SO is it possible to have the java code press the enter for me so that the process is fully automatic? I added the program to terminate in 5 seconds simply for testing purposes. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class runADP 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("Opening WinSCP");
                Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runTime.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe");
                try 
                {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        Robot r = null;
                            try 
                            {
                                r = new Robot();
                                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                            } 
                            catch (AWTException e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            System.out.println("Closing WinSCP");
            process.destroy();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 }
```

}

Comment: you may need to focus the application

Comment: Yeah I thought of trying something like that, trying to focus the application to bring the frame to the front, but could not find anything to accomplish this. Also I do not think this will entirely work because I do not have to click the client when I wish to login (i.e when I hit the enter key manually it still works fine. WIthout clicking the client to focus it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. The two keypress lines were being executed before the client could open. I simply added a thread.sleep command surrounded by a try and catch block and now the code works perfectly.

```
    public void go()
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Opening WinSCP");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe");
            Robot r = null;
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                r = new Robot();
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            } 
            catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```